# Ubuntu-live USB: rescue htdocs

Tags: live-usb

my openSUSE installation starts with a black screen due to driver problems. In attempt to save all data I am using an Ubuntu live stick. The problem is the folder /opt/ is shown as empty. Is there a way to save the files in the htdocs folder which was originally created by xampp in /opt/lampp/htdocs?

/etc/fstab

```
UUID=e5b9014b-2429-41da-8f19-ea94a22a7421 swap swap defaults 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 / btrfs defaults 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /boot/grub2/i386-pc btrfs subvol=@/boot/grub2/i386-pc 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /boot/grub2/x86_64-efi btrfs subvol=@/boot/grub2/x86_64-efi 0 0
UUID=8a098622-b4e4-4daa-ac24-ba6806f53c24 /home                xfs        defaults              1 2
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /opt btrfs subvol=@/opt 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /srv btrfs subvol=@/srv 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /tmp btrfs subvol=@/tmp 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /usr/local btrfs subvol=@/usr/local 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /var/crash btrfs subvol=@/var/crash 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /var/lib/libvirt/images btrfs subvol=@/var/lib/libvirt/images 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /var/lib/mailman btrfs subvol=@/var/lib/mailman 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /var/lib/mariadb btrfs subvol=@/var/lib/mariadb 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /var/lib/mysql btrfs subvol=@/var/lib/mysql 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /var/lib/named btrfs subvol=@/var/lib/named 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /var/lib/pgsql btrfs subvol=@/var/lib/pgsql 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /var/log btrfs subvol=@/var/log 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /var/opt btrfs subvol=@/var/opt 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /var/spool btrfs subvol=@/var/spool 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /var/tmp btrfs subvol=@/var/tmp 0 0
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /.snapshots btrfs subvol=@/.snapshots 0 0
```

Edit:
I managed now to copy (with a terminal in opensuse) the htdocs folder to /home, backuped it and reinstalled

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! That really depends on how the partitions where mounted on the other Linux system, namely the contents of `/etc/fstab` in the OpenSuse root drive.

Comment: Thank you! I added the content of the fstab file. Does this help? Is there a way to mount the opt folder?

Comment: `/opt` is mounted on a different partition, did you open that one as well for backing up the files?

Comment: I managed now to copy the htdocs folder to /home, backuped it and reinstalled

Comment: Ok then I am going to move my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in `/etc/fstab` shows that `/opt` is in a different partition:

```
UUID=07ba41aa-a03b-4fee-a2c3-8c8cb852fab0 /opt btrfs subvol=@/opt 0 0
```

It's normal that you see `/opt` empty, because that's a mount point that will get mapped to *that other partition* when the system boots.

You need to open the correct partition in order to back up the files contained in `/opt/lampp/htdocs`.